# Set a password that requires another password to be changed in Windows

Tags: windows, password-protection

Is it possible to set a password p1 for Windows (7 and/or 10) and define another password p2 that will be required to modify p1.

My need is to share an admin password but prevent the others to change it, and have access to the same account.

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

May be a better idea to create an account with Admin rights for the others to use, then use lusrmgr.msc from the "main" Admin account (yours) to disable the ability for that password to be changed ...

Handing out Admin passwords is always dangerous, but sometimes it is neccessary.... What permissions then are needed by the others that they have to have Admin access?

Comment: My distribution is not bundled with lusrmgr.msc utility. 
It seems that it’s impossible to set the specific workflow described in the question above. So I can change the plan. I want to allow an operator to restricted operations, namely: use a browser for search and handle word+excel for reporting, and I want to have access to all his files in his account/session.
The operator cannot tweak windows, install programs, have inaccessible files within his session …

Comment: OK, but why does that user need to have Admin rights?  The operations described above can be handled from a "standard" account. Also, what distro are you using that doesn't include **lusrmgr.msc**? I thought that was standard ...